# Is there a way in Java to check the availability of a network printer?

Tags: java, printing

I tried to use javax.print libraries to check for the network printer status without an effect results. the only 4 attributes i am getting are the following:

queued-job-count , printer-name, printer-is-accepting-jobs, color-supported

I need more detailed status such as "out of paper" and things like that. I read about PrinterStateReason but couldn't know how to implement.
Any ideas how to do that?